# Field userRepository in com.project.hostel.controller required a bean of type 'com.project.hostel.UserRepository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i am facing this error in spring boot:
Field userRepository in com.project.hostel.controller required a bean of type 'com.project.hostel.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.project.hostel.UserRepository' in your configuration.

Controller

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;



@RestController
public class controller {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayhello() {
       return "Hello Husnain";
    }
    @PostMapping(path = "/add")
    public String addUser(User u)
    {
        return "User ADDED";
    }

    
}
```

HostelApplication

```
package com.project.hostel;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication

public class HostelApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HostelApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

User Model

```
package com.project.hostel;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private  int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
package com.project.hostel;


import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Integer> {


}
```

DB my sql Connection:

```
#configuration
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_schema
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=husnain123

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

i want to just add user in database sql

Comment: you are missing `@EnableJpaRepositories`